# date picker should appear when clicked on image

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, mootools

In fiddle i am displaying a dynamic date picker which displays date when we put curser on that text box, that is fine.i want a image to be placed right side of text box and when image will be clicked then same date picker will be displayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/

I am trying by putting an image there but when i click on that image nothing happens. How can it be done? Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there is an option for this very thing: *toggleElements*. It expects a collection of other elements that can also invoke the datepicker. I added an array with a single element and it seems to work just fine.

```
var dp = new DatePicker('.picker', {
  pickerClass: 'datepicker ',
  allowEmpty: true,
  toggleElements: ['imageInvokerP']
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/10/

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am not getting it properly, can you please display in a fiddle

Comment: ya thanks a lot  i got it but when i am choosing a date from the picker then after clicking on that image, the selective date is not entered in that text box, please have a look at fiddle

Comment: @saroj I see the problem. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @saroj Forget everything that has been said up to now - I was reading through the datepicker source and discovered an optional collection of `toggleElements` which permits other elements (such as an image) to toggle the datepicker.

Comment: i faced another problem which i have asked,any solution please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397240/date-picker-not-appearing-after-clicking-on-image

Answer (score 0):

one ans was given by Jonathan and this should be the way of doing things of these kinds. 
but therez an easy solution you can take
assuming id of your image is `Image` and that of text box is `Input`
you can do everything normally
 binding the datepicker to the input element using `$('#Input').datePicker()` in `document.Ready`
next you can bind the click event of the $('#Image') like this

```
$('#Image').click(function(){
$('#Input').click();
});
```

this way automatically your input element will get focus when you will click on the image.