# date picker not appearing after clicking on image

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, mootools

I have a fiddle which displays date picker. same code i have written below but nothing happens, what wrong i am doing? When i click on that green colour then no date picker is generated, but in fiddle it is coming fine, where i am doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/10/

```
  <html>
   <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>//mootools script  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datepicker.css" />

   </head>
   <body>

  <input name='date_allow_empty' type='text' value='' class='date picker' />
  <div id="invokeDP"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">           
       var dp = new DatePicker('.picker', {
  pickerClass: 'datepicker ',
  allowEmpty: true,
  toggleElements: ['invokeDP']
  });    
     </script>  

   </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: I have taken all scripts inside `head` section, previously these scripts were in `body` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss a `mootools core library`.

```
<script src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js"></script>
```

Here is my working solution http://jsbin.com/unosar/4/edit#source *(click at Render button to preview)*

Comment: just one doubt, is it possible to display date picker when i will put cursor on that text box, without clicking on that green color? that is in 2 ways: first one is by clicking that color that is fine and also by just putting cursor on that text box, date picker will appear. Any solution please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/ like this, but problem is when i am displaying date picker, then the 1st one that is date picker should appear when color is clicked, is not working

Comment: It seem hard to me, sorry @saroj I'm not good at mootools. Suggest you  post on a new question then.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS isn't being detected because you have your `link` in the `body`. If I remove the CSS from your fiddle, it doesn't display at all:

http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/11/

Try moving this to the `head` tag along with your `script` elements. I've also changed your comment block to the correct HTML syntax:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script><!-- mootools script -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>     
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>
   .......
```

Also, your class for the `input` is `date picker`. Looking at your mootools script, this should be `datepicker`.

Comment: yes Curt i have written like that , what you have mentioned but still i am getting no result

Comment: Are the files `mootools-yui-compressed.js`, `datepicker.js` & `datepicker.css` all in the same folder as your HTML page?

Comment: yes all these 3 files including the html page are inside `web` folder

Comment: ya i edited but no date picker is generating after clicking on green colour, is it working on your computer?